# Rewrite rule .htaccess with one slash at the end of link

Tags: php, regex, apache

I need one slash to end of all links in my site after rewriting. How can I get it?
I need to remove all extraneous slashes except one from the end of my URLs. For example:

`http://www.mydomen.com/test///` should be rewritten to `http://www.mydomen.com/test/`

I've tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)//$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

But it doesn't work. What's the correct rewrite rule to do this?

Comment: `I need one slash to end of all links in my site after rewriting.` - why?

Comment: true answer: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/{2,}$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/+$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

Answer (score 0):

Try `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1/ [L,R=301]`

Comment: this will redirect you all the time :) and you will go into a loop... because `.*` matches everything. even nothing :) `*` means `0 to n` and `.` means `any character`

Answer (score 0):

is this working?:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)/{2,}$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

And make sure this is at the beginning of your `.htaccess` file. the `[L]` stands for `Last`

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \/{2,}$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/+$ /$1/ [L,R=301] Finally found! Thanks for the help)

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/]) /$1 [L,R=301]
```